# How to replace button with an animation in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, animation, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` in my code that moves steadily across the screen. Currently, when the user presses the button, the alpha changes to 0 and it just disappears. What I'd like to do is run a separate animation after the button is pressed/it has disappeared. Seems easy enough but the catch is I need to run the animation at the exact point of the button when it is pressed. And I'm drawing a blank on how to make this happen. Any help will be much appreciated! I'll post some relevant code below.

```
-(void)movingbuttons{
    movingButton2.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
    displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveObject)];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

-(void)moveObject{
    movingButton2.center = CGPointMake(movingButton2.center.x , movingButton2.center.y +1);
}


-(IBAction)button2:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [movingButton2 setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: See my update, added a more complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your animation with:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
             animations:^{
                 self.movingbutton2.alpha = 0.0;
                             // modify other animatable view properties here, ex:
                             self.someOtherView.alpha = 1.0;
             }
             completion:nil];
```

Just a nit picking point, but is the button in your view controller's .xib file correctly hooked up to your IBOutlets  and IBActions?

**UPDATE**:

You are not limited to modifying that one button in your method. You add what ever code you want in the animation block (see the udated axample above).

`UIView` animatable [properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html), there is an animation section there.

Another approach could be (I am just using `alpha` as an example):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     self.movingButton2.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:^{
                     [UIView animatateWithDuration:0.25
                                        animations:^{
                                            self.someOtherView.alpha = 1.0;
                                        }
                                       completion:nil];
  }];
```

This will more likely guarantee the animations will hapen one after another.

Comment: Okay, do you know how would I have the second animation run at the same point as the disappeared button?

Comment: @Dave123 I would modify properties you want in the first block, like the first example I gave.

Comment: @Dave123 You are welcome. Please take the time to up vote all the helpful answers, and if possible, mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your **button2** action with below code and implement the **someOtherMethodWithAnimation** method with the animation you want :)

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
 movingButton2.alpha = 0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self performSelector:@selector(someOtherMethodWithAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Comment: Alright, do you know how I'd run the second animation at the same point as the disappeared button?

Comment: your disappearing animation runs for 1 second and someOtherMethodWithAnimation runs exactly at the same point when the first animation finishes.